# present/dismissModalViewController causes UINavigationBar "Back" to lose animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, modal-dialog, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a UITableViewController that pushes a UIViewController using a UINavigationController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

In the detailViewController, I present a modal view when the user taps a button (a MFMessageComposeViewController for sending an SMS message) and then dismiss it, like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:smsViewController animated:YES];
...
// user pushes Send or Cancel button on the view
...
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The SMS modal view dismisses properly, but now when I click the "Back" button on the UINavigationBar, the views don't animate back to the table view.  The detail view just disappears and the UITableViewController's view is there.  The Back button animates and fades and the selected table cell still has the fading blue effect, but there's no view animation.

Does anyone know why the views don't animate properly?  If I don't open the SMS modal view, then the animation works properly, so I'm pretty sure it's caused somehow by the modal behavior.

Here's how my Interface Builder view arrangement looks for this Tab Bar Item:

[image: View Arrangement]

Comment: Have you tried this without animation?? I don't find any reason that might be causing the same issue. this is a very common practice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  Try what without animation?  If I change any of the YES's to NO's from my code snippets, I'm not sure what it would accomplish.  It just makes those behaviors non-animated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered my problem.  I am using a custom UITabBarController subclass that overrides `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` with some custom tab bar handling.  However, I wasn't calling `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` in the overridden method.  Yes, a sad day in my developer life.  It still seems odd to me that this would cause the behavior I experienced, but I'm certain it's now fixed due to this change.

Interestingly, the modal push/dismiss animation works properly without the `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` call in the iPhone 4.3 simulator.  But, it does not work in the iPhone 5.0 or 5.1 simulators.  (I used a non-MFMessageComposeViewController to text the modal behavior on the iPhone simulator since SMS isn't supported on the simulator).

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line `[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController];`
to

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

And check whether your detailView's `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods set to`YES`.

Comment: Oops, I missed the `animated:YES` in my copy/paste for the code snippet.  It's fixed now.  Interesting, when I implement `-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated` in the detailViewController and print the `animated` value, it changes to NO when the modal view is presented and displayed.  Why does this happen, and how can I change `animated` back to YES?

Comment: are you setting `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` to YES ? Please set your modal view's both method to YES.

Comment: In detailViewController, I set both `[self viewWillAppear:YES];` and `[self viewWillDisappear:YES];` after the `[self presentModalViewController:smsModalView animated:YES];` and `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, but to no effect.  Other suggestions?  Again, the modal view animates fine, just not the detailView back to the table view.

Comment: without showing the modalview just press back, is it animating ?

Comment: Yes.  If I select an item on the table view and click "Back" on the detailView without opening the modal view, the animation works fine.

Comment: `[self presentModalViewController:smsModalView animated:NO];` and `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` please check this too. Hope it will work.

Comment: Hm, tried that too, but it didn't work.  Thanks for your help.